# Exception while reading an excel sheet

Tags: python, pandas, pyspark, hdfs

I'm reading an excel sheet from an excel and I need to store that data as json in HDFS. For some sheets I'm facing the exception

```
excel_file = pd.ExcelFile("export_n_moreExportData10846.xls")
for sheet_name in excel_file.sheet_names:
df = pd.read_excel(excel_file, header=None, squeeze=True, sheet_name=sheet_name)
if sheet_name=='Passed':
    print '**************' + sheet_name + '******************'
    for i, row in df.iterrows():
        data = df.iloc[(i+1):].reset_index(drop=True)
        data.columns = pd.Series(list(df.iloc[i])).str.replace(' ','_')
        break

    for c in data.columns:
        data[c] = pd.to_numeric(data[c], errors='ignore')
    print data #I'm able to print the data

    result1 = sparkSession.createDataFrame(data) #Facing the exception here
    print "inserting data into HDFS..."
    result1.write.mode("append").json(hdfsPath)
    print "inserted data into hdfs"
```

I'm facing the below exception

```
raise TypeError("Can not merge type %s and %s" % (type(a), type(b)))
TypeError: Can not merge type <class 'pyspark.sql.types.StringType'> and <class 'pyspark.sql.types.DoubleType'>
```

Image shows the data

[image]

Comment: Can you post the pandas dataframe you have printed ( print data)

Comment: I have added the data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably because some of the columns have different data types in the same column, pandas can handle that ('object' type), spark df can not.

couple of ways of dealing with this:

1. you can skip the spark df stage, invert the pandas df to dicts (df.to_dict(orient='records') and read those to an RDD and save that (consider converting to proper jsons with json loads and dumps).
2. cast object columns to string (df[col] = df[col].astype(str)).

depends on what you want exactly.

For this data.fillna('0', inplace=True) worked since the columns has empty records.

Comment: I'll need a sample data for that

Comment: I have added the data

Comment: kind of hard to use this (OCR needed :)) ,but looking at it seems that your problem is not as I thought, rather it is a null problem at "TR defect" which is not a string, try df.fillna(0) and let us know what happens

Comment: I used data.fillna(0). On printing data the values are NaN in 'TR Defect' column except the last one

Comment: perhaps it was not saved, try data.fillna('0', inplace=True) or data=data.filna('0')

Comment: Thanku somuch @Ezer. data.fillna('0', inplace=True) worked !!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/163721/discussion-between-krishna-and-ezer-k).